# Getting data from Point and/or Spotlight sources from Blender

Tags: c++, blender

I'm trying to get information form a spotlight object from blender. I'm able to get the information however when I try to upload it to my cpu the information isn't stored anywhere.

```
//Load the level
GW::SYSTEM::GLog trackLevel;
trackLevel.EnableConsoleLogging(true);
trackLevel.Create("ProgressLog.txt");
trackLevel.Log("Start Program.");
cpuLevel.LoadLevel("../GameLevel.txt", "../BlenderObjects", trackLevel.Relinquish());
trackLevel.Log("End Program.");
```

So how this code works is it reads in the matrix information from a text file and grabs the .h2b files from a folder in the same directory it seems that when I try to access the light .h2b file it isn't read.

I tried making a container for it but it didn't seem to go into that contain since it isn't being read. This is the code I'm using to grab the information.

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy_extras.io_utils import axis_conversion
import mathutils
import math

print("----------Begin Level Export----------")

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath), "GameLevel.txt")
file = open(path, "w")
file.write("# Game Level Exporter v1.0\n")

scene = bpy.context.scene

def export_spot_light(light):
    file.write("LIGHT\n")
    file.write(light.name + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.type) + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.energy) + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.spot_size) + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.matrix_world) + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.color) + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.location) + "\n")
    file.write(str(light.rotation_euler) + "\n")
    file.write("\n")

def traverse_objects(obj):
    if obj.type == 'LIGHT':
        export_spot_light(obj)

    for child in obj.children:
        traverse_objects(child)

def print_heir(ob, levels=10):
    def recurse(ob, parent, depth):
        if depth > levels: 
            return
        # spacing to show hierarchy
        spaces = "  " * depth
        # print to system console for debugging
        print(spaces, ob.type)
        print(spaces, ob.name)
        print(spaces, ob.matrix_world)
        # send to file
        file.write(spaces + ob.type + "\n")
        file.write(spaces + ob.name + "\n")
        
        # swap from blender space to vulkan/d3d 
        # { rx, ry, rz, 0 } to { rx, rz, ry, 0 }  
        # { ux, uy, uz, 0 }    { ux, uz, uy, 0 }
        # { lx, ly, lz, 0 }    { lx, lz, ly, 0 } 
        # { px, py, pz, 1 }    { px, pz, py, 1 }  
        row_world = ob.matrix_world.transposed()
        converted = mathutils.Matrix.Identity(4)
        converted[0][0:3] = row_world[0][0], row_world[0][2], row_world[0][1]
        converted[1][0:3] = row_world[1][0], row_world[1][2], row_world[1][1] 
        converted[2][0:3] = row_world[2][0], row_world[2][2], row_world[2][1] 
        converted[3][0:3] = row_world[3][0], row_world[3][2], row_world[3][1]  
        
        # flip the local Z axis for winding and transpose for export
        scaleZ = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(-1.0, 4, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
        converted = scaleZ.transposed() @ converted  
        file.write(spaces + str(converted) + "\n")
         
        # TODO: For a game-ready exporter, we would
        # probably want the delta(pivot) matrix, lights,
        # detailed mesh hierarchy information
        # and bounding box/collision data at a minimum

        for child in ob.children:
            recurse(child, ob,  depth + 1)

    recurse(ob, ob.parent, 0)

root_objects = [obj for obj in scene
    traverse_objects(obj)

file.close()
```

Comment: the only code I see is a few log calls and a function call with string arguments, not particular Blender code